# How can Uniswap instance ERC20 tokens without importing code?

Tags: solidity, erc-20, uniswap, import

I was checking [Uniswap contracts github repo](https://github.com/Uniswap/uniswap-v2-core/blob/master/contracts/UniswapV2Factory.sol) and I don't understand exactly how can they dynamically use any ERC20 tokens without importing the code or having the ERC20 token smart contract address.

I know that the magic is in this function, specially in assembly create2 function, but cannot understand it properly.

```
function createPair(address tokenA, address tokenB) external returns (address pair) {
    require(tokenA != tokenB, 'UniswapV2: IDENTICAL_ADDRESSES');
    (address token0, address token1) = tokenA < tokenB ? (tokenA, tokenB) : (tokenB, tokenA);
    require(token0 != address(0), 'UniswapV2: ZERO_ADDRESS');
    require(getPair[token0][token1] == address(0), 'UniswapV2: PAIR_EXISTS'); // single check is sufficient
    bytes memory bytecode = type(UniswapV2Pair).creationCode;
    bytes32 salt = keccak256(abi.encodePacked(token0, token1));
    assembly {
        pair := create2(0, add(bytecode, 32), mload(bytecode), salt)
    }
    IUniswapV2Pair(pair).initialize(token0, token1);
    getPair[token0][token1] = pair;
    getPair[token1][token0] = pair; // populate mapping in the reverse direction
    allPairs.push(pair);
    emit PairCreated(token0, token1, pair, allPairs.length);
}
```

Could anyone provide further information?

Answer (score 1):

`createPair` takes two ERC20 contract addresses as input, and returns the address of this pair. This address is deterministically calculated using the [CREATE2 opcode](https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/blob/master/EIPS/eip-1014.md). Therefore all information is inherently available and no addresses need to be hardcoded. `getPair` gets dynamically populated with pair addresses.